# How to move the line following the circle to the bottom of the circle

Tags: css

I am working on a multiple-step progress bar. I need to put the circles (representing the steps) on top of the the lines. I add the line to a circle using `:after`. I used `z-index` to put the circle always on top, but it did not work. Any ideas?

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaqz77qf/1/

```css
.visuallyhidden {
  display: none;
}
.wizard-progress {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wizard-progress li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.wizard-progress .step-name {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 32px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.wizard-progress .step-name-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.wizard-progress .step-num {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}
.wizard-progress .step-num:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #CCC;
  height: 15px;
  width: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  left: 58px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.wizard-progress li:last-of-type .step-num:after {
  display: none;
}
.wizard-progress .active-step .step-num {
  background-color: #ff0500;
}
```

```html
<ol class="wizard-progress clearfix">
  <li class="active-step">
    <span class="step-name">
            Foo
        </span>
    <span class="visuallyhidden">Step </span>
    <span class="step-num">1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="step-name">Bar</span>
    <span class="visuallyhidden">Step </span>
    <span class="step-num">&hearts;</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="step-name">Baz</span>
    <span class="visuallyhidden">Step </span>
    <span class="step-num">3</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="step-name">Quux</span>
    <span class="visuallyhidden">Step </span>
    <span class="step-num">4</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your z-index to -1 and the circle layers on top of the bar, I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
Line 56:       z-index: -1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, I just tried -1 and it worked, perhaps someone more experienced can explain why 0 isn't working.

Comment: @BrianCombs 0 is defaut and stands in and on top of parent itself.

Comment: this explains z index http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/what-you-may-not-know-about-the-z-index-property--webdesign-16892